# Does iOS has similar method that android has android.net.Network::bindSocket

Tags: ios, networking

Does iOS have similar method that android has android.net.Network::bindSocket ?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket(java.net.DatagramSocket)

I would like to have access to cellar and wifi from iOS app at same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BSD sockets to bind for cellar IP address.

It should direct your traffic throw cellar network.

[Does IOS support simultaneous wifi and 3g/4g connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755051/does-ios-support-simultaneous-wifi-and-3g-4g-connections)